# installing ubuntu along with windows 8

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

sir
unfortunately my copy of windows8 was not genuine and i am unable to install Ubuntu 12.01 version if the formatting is the way i lost most of my data so my query is thier any possibility of installing Ubuntu along with windows please reply

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [video demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNCSbTyUzoM) of how to Dual boot windows 8 with Ubuntu.